# What does いなきゃ mean?

Tags: て-form, contractions, negation

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Difference between ~なきゃ　and ~なくちゃ](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/questions/4213/difference-between-%e3%81%aa%e3%81%8d%e3%82%83%e3%80%80and-%e3%81%aa%e3%81%8f%e3%81%a1%e3%82%83)

What does いなきゃ mean?

Comment: okay i did it. w

Comment: ？？？*************

Comment: You said I must edit my question。ですよね？！

Comment: @konan-san,  I didn't say that... must have been someone else...

Answer (score 3):

「いなきゃ」 is short for 「いなければ」.

1. いなきゃ ≒ いなければ ≒ いないのであれば  'If (someone) is not (somewhere)...'

   > e.g. 君がいなきゃ、会議が始められないよ。
   > We can't begin the meeting without you.
2. いなきゃ ≒ いなければ ≒ いなければならない '(Someone) has to be (somewhere).'

   > e.g. 君がいなきゃ。
   > We can't do without you (=You have to be here).

Comment: ありがとうございますよ！！！！

Comment: lol, どういたしまして!!! （「よ」は要らないね！）