How is the grammar working in いや、何かしないとな?
From what I've gathered. The sentence いや、何かしないとな means something like "No, I've got to do something" .
I cant quite understand how the grammar is working here to turn the negative suru verb into a positive sentence.

Does this answer your question: https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/52627/9831 / https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/9490/9831

と normally means that the sentence is a conditional: if you do that, then something happens:
何かをしないと、問題がある。
It's common in Japanese to keep the first part (ending with と) and remove the second part, in which case the intended meaning is "if I don't that, then it's bad", in other words "I have to do that".
