# What does なきや mean?

Tags: translation, meaning

I assume this is some sort of idiom or verbal tic, but i'm not 100% sure. Anybody care to help me out?

If you need context, this is the phrase:
まだピチピチなんだからかんばらなきや

Comment: possible duplicate of [Difference between ~なきゃ　and ~なくちゃ](http://japanese.stackexchange.com/questions/4213/difference-between-%e3%81%aa%e3%81%8d%e3%82%83%e3%80%80and-%e3%81%aa%e3%81%8f%e3%81%a1%e3%82%83)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

~なきゃ is a contraction of ~なければ. なきや could be a typo or unusual spelling of this.

~なければならない makes a verb imperative, for example

> 行かなければならない
>   (I) must go

The ならない is often informally omitted.

In the case of your example sentence the verb is [頑張]{がんば}る, becoming 頑張らなきゃ to give the meaning "I must do my best"

Comment: I see, I'm still trying to understand informal contractions in Japanese. Thank you!

Comment: @DivineRho No problem. For future reference also note the correct spelling of the verb がんばる :)

Comment: As a supplement, the omitted subject may not be “I.”  So the sentence in the question may mean “You are still young, so work hard!”

Comment: Splitting hairs here, and I may not even be right, but I thought ~なきゃ was a contraction of ~なくては. なくては -> なくちゃ -> なきゃ.

Comment: No, なくては only contracts to なくちゃ. Note similar examples to なきゃ for なければ, such as 悪けりゃ for 悪ければ.