# Doubt about syntax

Tags: syntax

コートを着なければいけません。

I'm not sure about the meaning of this sentence. Would it be something like "If you don't wear a coat, you're not going"?

Comment: Related: http://japanese.stackexchange.com/questions/2500/must-do-%ef%bd%9e%e3%81%aa%e3%81%91%e3%82%8c%e3%81%b0%e3%81%aa%e3%82%89%e3%81%aa%e3%81%84-vs-%ef%bd%9e%e3%81%aa%e3%81%8f%e3%81%a6%e3%81%af%e3%81%84%e3%81%91%e3%81%aa%e3%81%84

Answer (score 2, accepted):

なければいけません means "must do".

So the translation becomes:
コートを着なければいけません。
You have to wear a coat.

なければいけません is one of the variants of なければならない。